# How will take time difference in SQL Server 24 hour format

Tags: sql-server

In my procedure I wrote a query to get the difference in hours of two dates.

In some cases I did not get correct difference.

This is my code:

```
Declare @@Totalwork as Float
set @Totalwork = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @fpunch, @SPunch))
set @Totalwork = (select ABS(@Totalwork)) 
set @totalWork = (select left((cast(@Totalwork as float) / 60), 3))
```

I did not get correct working hours when I am using two times in the `datediff` function. Actually I want correct difference.

I putting value here below.

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '10:15', '00:15')
```

here 10:15 is the morning time and 00:15 is early morning time.

How will I convert a time into 24 hour format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate using datetime

```
Declare @Totalwork as datetime
SET @Totalwork= @SPunch - @fpunch
```

Here are some different ways of calculating it:

```
SELECT 
  datediff(hour, 0, @Totalwork) [hours],
  datediff(minute, 0, @Totalwork) % 60 [remaining minutes],
  datediff(minute, 0, @Totalwork) totalminutes
  cast(@Totalwork as time) [timedifference],
  @Totalwork actualdifference,
  cast(@Totalwork as float) / 24 decimalhours
```

Comment: then how take accurate hours in Digits

Comment: here I have got one problem .If we enter 10:00 pm as first punch and  after one day 00:20 am as second punch. time difference displaying is not correct

Comment: @Nuyan I was assuming you were using datetimes to punch in and punch out. According to your text, they are both dates